# Error when setting cookie

Tags: errors, session, cookies

I get this error when trying to set a cookie on a WP page.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(...)
```

Any help here? It worked fine when I did the php outside of wordpress, but when I move it in, it broke. Nothing special about the cookie(very basic).

So how do I get the cookie to set?

Answer (score 1):

You set the cookie too late. You can use any action before `template_include` to set a cookie, after that there is already HTML output, and no further headers can be set.

Example:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    setcookie( 'test', 1 );
});
```